# How can I change the permissions of a role in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to make a command to change the permissions of a certain role so it has admin.

I've tried:

```
if(message.content.toString() == '!admin') {
    var role = '649795089606115329';
    role.edit({permissions: 'ADMINISTRATOR'})
}
```

and I got the error:

```
TypeError: role.edit is not a function
```

Not sure how else to go about this

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you haven't got the role, to do this you need to do the following

```js
const theguild = client.guilds.get("The_server_id");
let therole = theguild.roles.get("The_role_id");
```

This gets the role object so you can use the methods (functions)

You may also want to look into the `role.setPermissions()` method to change the permissions instead of `role.edit()`

so you will want something like this

```js
const server = client.guilds.get("The_server_id");
const role = server.roles.get("649795089606115329");

role.setPermissions(["ADMINISTRATOR"])
  .then(updated => console.log("Updated permissions to " + updated.permissions.bitfield))
  .catch(console.error);
```